# Bootstrap CSS and pandas DataFrame.to_html. How to add class to <thead>?

Tags: html, css, pandas, flask

I'm using the bootstrap.min.css for stylesheets in my Flask app and am styling the data tables outputted by Pandas in the following manner:

```
result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result, orient='index', columns = [var2use]).to_html(classes='table table-striped table-hover', header = "true", justify = "center")
```

Everything is working very well and stylings are applied as hoped. One thing I cannot figure out is how to also add in the `.thead-light` or dark styling to this?

I'm using these as resources

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

I've tried adding to this part `classes='table table-striped table-hover'` something like `classes='table table-striped table-hover thead-light'` but that styling doesn't appear.

Any suggestions on how to style my table so the header has that styling applied in the Flask app (hopefully without having to write additional .css)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DataFrame.to_html` method only supports adding classes to the table element itself, so there's no way to apply a class to the `thead` from Python.

A workaround for this would be to use javascript to apply the desired class when the page loads.  Just add this script to your template, before the `</body>` end tag:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.onload = function() {
    const thead = document.querySelectorAll('.table > thead');
    thead.forEach(e => e.classList.add('thead-light'));
  }
</script>
```

This will add the `thead-light` class to the `<thead>` of every table with class `table` on your page.

Comment: Works well. (I used jquery)

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use JS you can also use string.replace():

```
df.to_html(classes="table").replace("<thead>", "<thead class='thead-light'>")
```

First header only:

```
df.to_html(classes="table").replace("<thead>", "<thead class='thead-light'>", 1)
```